# Emiting MSIL to emit MSIL runs into JIT Limitation

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

So I wanted to answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22921/12097 and decided to emit MSIL code to do the integer addition. Since this was successful, I then decided to emit MSIL code, which emits my first code. So calling the code constructs a method, which constructs a method that calls `int.op_Addition`. This fails miserably with the JIT complaining that I have gone too far! Duh!

The exception is `System.SystemException: {"JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation."}` on the last line when the dynamic method is called.

My question is, I am correct in assuming that emitting code to emit code is somehow disallowed by the JIT. The alternative is that I made a misake, which is likely, but I checked my code against MSIL code generated by `Reflector`.

Here is the code, for your amusement:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int z2=Add2(1, 2);
        // z2 = "JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation."
    }

    // Emit MSIL to emit MSIL
    public static int Add2(int x, int y)
    {
        Type delegate_type=typeof(Func<int, int, int>);
        DynamicMethod method=new DynamicMethod(typeof(Program).ToString()+".GenAdd",
            typeof(int),
            new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }, typeof(Program));
        ILGenerator generator=method.GetILGenerator();

        LocalBuilder method1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(DynamicMethod));
        LocalBuilder generator1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(ILGenerator));
        LocalBuilder add1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        LocalBuilder args1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(Type[]));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));            

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, 
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle", 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, ".op_Addition");                        
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,                
            typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat",
                new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) } ));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(Type));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(Program));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetConstructor(
                new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Type), typeof(Type[]) }));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetMethod("GetILGenerator",
                Type.EmptyTypes));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("DeclareLocal",
                new Type[] { typeof(Type) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldarg_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldarg_1",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Add",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Stloc_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldloc_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ret",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetMethod("CreateDelegate",
                new Type[] { typeof(Type)} ));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(Func<int, int, int>).GetMethod("Invoke",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Func<int, int, int> add2=method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>)) as Func<int, int, int>;

        return add2(x, y);
    }
}
```

I expect `Add2` to generate code that looks like this, which works 100% correctly:

```
    // Emit MSIL directly
    public static int Add1(int x, int y)
    {
        Type delegate_type=typeof(Func<int, int, int>);
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(typeof(int).ToString()+".op_Addition",
            typeof(int),
            new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }, typeof(Program));

        ILGenerator generator=method.GetILGenerator();
        LocalBuilder result=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Func<int, int, int> add=method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>)) as Func<int, int, int>;

        return add(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: If there was something wrong with the code it would produce a `System.SystemException:{"Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."}`

Comment: Thanks to Ben the code works now, and there isn't an issue with `JIT` after all. FYI - Here is the code contest post: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23305/12097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite certain that the JIT is able to compile code that uses Reflection.  If not, you wouldn't be able to use `Reflection.Emit`, ever.  The MSIL you generate goes through the same JIT process as MSIL generated by the C# compiler.

There is a bit of a difference when it comes to CAS checks, but I see nothing to suggest that you're operating in a partial trust scenario to begin with.

I see this line:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
typeof(DynamicMethod).GetConstructor(
    new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Type), typeof(Type[]) }));
```

which locates the `DynamicMethod(string, Type, Type[])` constructor that creates an anonymously-hosted method.  But in `Add1`, you have

```
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(typeof(int).ToString()+".op_Addition",
                                         typeof(int),
                                         new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }, 
                                         typeof(Program));
```

which calls the four-argument `DynamicMethod` constructor, that adds a method to the type `Program`.

As a result, there's a complete mismatch of the types on the operand stack when you use `newobj`.

Comment: I am going for this constructor `public DynamicMethod(string name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner);`. You are right. It works now.